# Getting DetailedApiRequestError when uploading a file to google drive with pre-generated file id

Tags: flutter, dart, google-drive-api

I want my users to be able to back-up their data on google drive. I used the "Try it now" tool of google drive to generate a file id, because if I don't set file id before uploading the file, the drive.files.create() method creates a new file id after every upload to google drive.

First I import google drive API.

```
import 'package:googleapis/drive/v3.dart' as ga;
```

This is how I create the file I want to upload:

```
// Create the file we want to upload.
ga.File fileToUpload = ga.File();
var file = await _localFile;
fileToUpload.parents = ["appDataFolder"];
fileToUpload.name = path.basename(file.absolute.path);
// Setting a generated id from the "Try it now" tool.
fileToUpload.id = "1azltlNpZEt6RyUBNwdYUAWPZv2o6w7bP";
```

And this is how I upload it to google drive:

```
var response = await drive.files.create(
    fileToUpload,
    uploadMedia: ga.Media(file.openRead(), file.lengthSync()),
  );
```

The response I get is: "Unhandled Exception: DetailedApiRequestError(status: 403, message: Method not supported for files within the Application Data folder.)"

If I remove the next line when I create the file:

```
fileToUpload.parents = ["appDataFolder"];
```

And then I try to upload the file, I get: "DetailedApiRequestError(status: 403, message: The user does not have sufficient permissions for this file.)"

If I don't set the file id, which means I remove the next line:

```
fileToUpload.id = "1azltlNpZEt6RyUBNwdYUAWPZv2o6w7bP";
```

Then I can upload the file to google drive. But it's not helping me because it creates a new file id.

Is there anything I can do?

Edit: The problem with google drive generating a new file Id every time the user syncing the app data on google drive, is that it means that after every sync, I need to save the new file id on a server (so I can retrieve the file when needed). And when there are many active users that backing their data multiple times a day, all those update calls to the service would cost me too much money. So I prefer that the file Id will always stay the same.

Comment: Hi ! In your case what is exaclty ```ga``` ? Your drive serivce? What is your issue with Drive generating an id for that file? Remember that every single file should have an unique id.

Comment: @MateoRandwolf Hi. I have updated my question, On the first line of code, you can see what is ga. On the bottom of the question, you can see why I prefer that the file Id will always be the same.

Comment: Hi ! Have you tried uploading to another Drive folder (not the hideen App Data folder)? Are you testing this on a phone and [**using the right Appdata scope**](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/appdata#application_data_folder_scope)?

Comment: With regards to the ID, if you try to create several files with the same account with the same ID you will encounter an error. In this case however, it seems that the user (you I believe) don't have write access to the file according to the [documented error](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/handle-errors#resolve_a_403_error_the_user_does_not_have_sufficient_permissions_for_file_fileid). I believe this might be an issue with the scopes you are using, could you describe them to me?